# ask with if input( ) is integer or not in python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to run this without any errors

```
A =input("How old are you:")
if A is int :
    print ("you are",A,"years old that's awesome")
else:
    print("error! type numbers only! ")
    exit()
```

Comment: In the future please explain the kind of errors you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

`input` always yields a string so `A` is always a string

so what you're looking for is a `try except block`

```
A =input("How old are you:")
try:
    int(A)
    print("you are {} years old that's awesome".format(A))
except(ValueError):
    print("error! type integers only!")
    exit()
```

if they don't give you an integer, then the int function will raise a value error. If a Value error is raised it will then print your error message and exit.

Your if statement wouldn't work, because a variable is not the same as its type. `5 is int` will return `False` while `5 is 5` returns `True`. Using exception handling is better for your task and makes your code more readable, since it appears that you want to consider it an error if the user doesn't enter an integer and that is what `try except` statements' original intent is.

Answer (score 0):

Use the method isdigit()

try this :

```
A = input("How old are you:")  
if A.isdigit() :  
     print ("you are",A,"years old that's awesome")  
else:  
     print("error! type numbers only! ")  
     exit()
```

Comment: (if someone edits your post youre supposed to wait for them to be approved in the queue if you agree or to edit if you disagree. We've been through this 5 times now and your post still isn't properly formatted)

Comment: @MatthewCiaramitaro, FYI: The author of the question or answer can unilaterally approve or reject suggested edits. Thus, there's no need for them to wait for the edit to be reviewed by other people. In fact, they have the option to unilaterally approve or reject the edit even after it's been approved or rejected in the review queue.